# Multiple layouts for different modules - Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, layout

I have a question about layouts in Zend Framework. 
This is my structure of my project:

- I have 2 modules named "backoffice" and "frontoffice".
- I have one layout.phtml in layouts/scripts for both the backoffice and frontoffice.
- Now I want seperate "layouts/scripts" for "backoffice" and "frontoffice"
- In my application.ini I have: `resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"`

Now how can I fix this that I have seperate layouts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just place another layout in the `layout/scripts` folder and tell any module, controller or action to use that other layout instead of the default layout.

If you want to let a controller use a different layout, you can place the following in your `init()`

```
$this->_helper->layout->setLayout('layoutname');
```

You can do that respectively for specific actions or for a whole module.

Answer (score 3):

Put this into your application.ini

```
resources.layout.layout = "layout"
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
```

Your layout file will be /modules/MODULE_NAME/views/scripts/layout.phtml

Answer (score 1):

You should write front controller plugin for that purpose (called layout selector).

In your Bootstrap.php register that plugin - layout selector:

```
protected function _initPlugins(){
    $front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
    $front->registerPlugin(new My_Plugins_LayoutSelector());
}
```

Auto load namespace My_ in application.ini

```
Autoloadernamespaces[] = "My_"
```

And finally, create in /library a new folder 'My' and in it folder 'Plugins' and in it file 'LayoutSelector.php' with code:

```
class My_Plugins_LayoutSelector extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract {
    public function preDispatch(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $request) {
        $module = $request->getModuleName();
        $layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
        $layout->setLayout($module);
    }
}
```

In this way every module in the future will use appropriate layout and no need to write in each controller to select layout.

Answer (score 0):

I use this custom plugin with some changes, and for each module I create specific layout, with specific structure
http://blog.vandenbos.org/2009/07/19/zend-framework-module-specific-layout/